# LUW DB2 JDBC Connection Issue on Open JDK 11

Tags: db2, db2-luw, openjdk-11

I am not able to connect LUW DB2 database using JDBC Type4 driver on `Open Zulu JDK 11`.

I have tried all available latest DB2 JDBC Drivers (Type 4) but same issue with all drivers on JDK 11. Things are working fine on JDK 8.

**Getting below error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "B"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.xc.<init>(xc.java:64)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.f.<init>(f.java:44)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.cb(b.java:1945)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.p.a(p.java:3284)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.a(b.java:625)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.<init>(b.java:334)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:165)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.aonhewitt.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

**Test Java Code**

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://hostname:port/database","userid","password");
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me here to connect to a DB2-LUW database from JDK 11

```
C:\>java -cp db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version 
IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.25.23 


C:\>java -cp jcc-11.5.4.0.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version 
IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.27.25
```

Comment: please edit your question to show the plain text output of this command line (which must run on the same machine where your java program runs, i.e. to use the exact same jarfile for db2jcc4.jar that you are using) `java -cp /your_path/db2jcc.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc  -version`  (replace `your_path` with your fully qualified pathname to the db2jcc4.jar file).

Comment: (use db2jcc4.jar in the command line, of course, after confirming that is what is loading). Ensure your CLASSPATH is correct and not loading older versions, or your `-cp ` command line if using.

Comment: C:\>java -cp db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version
IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.25.23

C:\>java -cp jcc-11.5.4.0.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version
IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.27.25

Comment: Connection to Db2-LUW works successfully for me:  `OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.41+23-CA (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)`  along with the `db2jcc4.jar` that is present in file `v11.5.4_jdbc_sqlj.tar.gz` .  You may have some configuration issue or made some mistake or omission when following IBM's instructions.

Comment: Finally issue resolved. Issue was with DB2 Driver. Thanks